# Python pandas: Datas are not displaying while running these below codes

Tags: pandas

I have ran the below code in jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as p
import os
jan = p.read_csv('C:/Users/1605786/OneDrive - TCS COM PROD/Documents/Pandas/Analysis/Sales_January_2019.csv')
jan.head()
```

O/p:

```
    Order ID    Product Quantity Ordered    Price Each  Order Date  Purchase Address
0   141234  iPhone  1   700 01/22/19 21:25  944 Walnut St, Boston, MA 02215
1   141235  Lightning Charging Cable    1   14.95   01/28/19 14:15  185 Maple St, Portland, OR 97035
2   141236  Wired Headphones    2   11.99   01/17/19 13:33  538 Adams St, San Francisco, CA 94016
3   141237  27in FHD Monitor    1   149.99  01/05/19 20:33  738 10th St, Los Angeles, CA 90001
4   141238  Wired Headphones    1   11.99   01/25/19 11:59  387 10th St, Austin, TX 73301
```

but if i run these below codes:

```
k = called[called.isna().any(axis=1)]
k
```

Getting output as below one. (Getting only column names not values)
O/p:

```
Order ID    Product Quantity Ordered    Price Each  Order Date  Purchase Address    Month
```

Comment: Can you include the output for called.info()?

Comment: No Luck Scott still getting the same error

Comment: No.  I need the information from called.info().  What does that print out?

Comment: In this question you show where you get jan dataframe but then you are trying to look at the called dataframe.  The two aren't related.

Comment: Yes before that i used this below code:

called = gen.fillna(method='bfill')
called

Comment: Can you show me what does 'called.info()' return?

Comment: I tried inplace=True. Not working while using variable

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 186850 entries, 0 to 11685
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------            --------------   ----- 
 0   Order ID          186850 non-null  object
 1   Product           186850 non-null  object
 2   Quantity Ordered  186850 non-null  object
 3   Price Each        186850 non-null  object
 4   Order Date        186850 non-null  object
 5   Purchase Address  186850 non-null  object
 6   Month             186850 non-null  object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 11.4+ MB